# How to fix the error 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 36188: character maps to <undefined>'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am training an AI to write a book using TensorFlow 1.14 and python 2.6.7. Whenever I run my training python code, I get the error message `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 36188: character maps to <undefined>` I have reinstalled TensorFlow and python as well as searched the forums to try and find an answer. The traceback leads me to a file called cp1252.py in the encodings folder

The code I'm running is

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import argparse
import time
import os
from six.moves import cPickle

from utils import TextLoader
from model import Model

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='data/tinyshakespeare',
                       help='data directory containing input.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--input_encoding', type=str, default=None,
                       help='character encoding of input.txt, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings')
    parser.add_argument('--log_dir', type=str, default='logs',
                       help='directory containing tensorboard logs')
    parser.add_argument('--save_dir', type=str, default='save',
                       help='directory to store checkpointed models')
    parser.add_argument('--rnn_size', type=int, default=256,
                       help='size of RNN hidden state')
    parser.add_argument('--num_layers', type=int, default=2,
                       help='number of layers in the RNN')
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default='lstm',
                       help='rnn, gru, or lstm')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=50,
                       help='minibatch size')
    parser.add_argument('--seq_length', type=int, default=25,
                       help='RNN sequence length')
    parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', type=int, default=50,
                       help='number of epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--save_every', type=int, default=1000,
                       help='save frequency')
    parser.add_argument('--grad_clip', type=float, default=5.,
                       help='clip gradients at this value')
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.002,
                       help='learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--decay_rate', type=float, default=0.97,
                       help='decay rate for rmsprop')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu_mem', type=float, default=0.666,
                       help='%% of gpu memory to be allocated to this process. Default is 66.6%%')
    parser.add_argument('--init_from', type=str, default=None,
                       help="""continue training from saved model at this path. Path must contain files saved by previous training process:
                            'config.pkl'        : configuration;
                            'words_vocab.pkl'   : vocabulary definitions;
                            'checkpoint'        : paths to model file(s) (created by tf).
                                                  Note: this file contains absolute paths, be careful when moving files around;
                            'model.ckpt-*'      : file(s) with model definition (created by tf)
                        """)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    train(args)

def train(args):
    data_loader = TextLoader(args.data_dir, args.batch_size, args.seq_length, args.input_encoding)
    args.vocab_size = data_loader.vocab_size

    # check compatibility if training is continued from previously saved model
    if args.init_from is not None:
        # check if all necessary files exist
        assert os.path.isdir(args.init_from)," %s must be a path" % args.init_from
        assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join(args.init_from,"config.pkl")),"config.pkl file does not exist in path %s"%args.init_from
        assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join(args.init_from,"words_vocab.pkl")),"words_vocab.pkl.pkl file does not exist in path %s" % args.init_from
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.init_from)
        assert ckpt,"No checkpoint found"
        assert ckpt.model_checkpoint_path,"No model path found in checkpoint"

        # open old config and check if models are compatible
        with open(os.path.join(args.init_from, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            saved_model_args = cPickle.load(f)
        need_be_same=["model","rnn_size","num_layers","seq_length"]
        for checkme in need_be_same:
            assert vars(saved_model_args)[checkme]==vars(args)[checkme],"Command line argument and saved model disagree on '%s' "%checkme

        # open saved vocab/dict and check if vocabs/dicts are compatible
        with open(os.path.join(args.init_from, 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            saved_words, saved_vocab = cPickle.load(f)
        assert saved_words==data_loader.words, "Data and loaded model disagree on word set!"
        assert saved_vocab==data_loader.vocab, "Data and loaded model disagree on dictionary mappings!"

    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
        cPickle.dump(args, f)
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
        cPickle.dump((data_loader.words, data_loader.vocab), f)

    model = Model(args)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(args.log_dir)
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=args.gpu_mem)

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
        train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        # restore model
        if args.init_from is not None:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        for e in range(model.epoch_pointer.eval(), args.num_epochs):
            sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.learning_rate * (args.decay_rate ** e)))
            data_loader.reset_batch_pointer()
            state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
            speed = 0
            if args.init_from is None:
                assign_op = model.epoch_pointer.assign(e)
                sess.run(assign_op)
            if args.init_from is not None:
                data_loader.pointer = model.batch_pointer.eval()
                args.init_from = None
            for b in range(data_loader.pointer, data_loader.num_batches):
                start = time.time()
                x, y = data_loader.next_batch()
                feed = {model.input_data: x, model.targets: y, model.initial_state: state,
                        model.batch_time: speed}
                summary, train_loss, state, _, _ = sess.run([merged, model.cost, model.final_state,
                                                             model.train_op, model.inc_batch_pointer_op], feed)
                train_writer.add_summary(summary, e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
                speed = time.time() - start
                if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.batch_size == 0:
                    print("{}/{} (epoch {}), train_loss = {:.3f}, time/batch = {:.3f}" \
                        .format(e * data_loader.num_batches + b,
                                args.num_epochs * data_loader.num_batches,
                                e, train_loss, speed))
                if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.save_every == 0 \
                        or (e==args.num_epochs-1 and b == data_loader.num_batches-1): # save for the last result
                    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'model.ckpt')
                    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
                    print("model saved to {}".format(checkpoint_path))
        train_writer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be appreciated
I can give any info needed
Edit: My Traceback is

````
  File "train.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 54, in main
    train(args)
  File "train.py", line 57, in train
    data_loader = TextLoader(args.data_dir, args.batch_size, args.seq_length, args.input_encoding)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\word-rnn-tensorflow-master\utils.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.preprocess(input_file, vocab_file, tensor_file, encoding)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\word-rnn-tensorflow-master\utils.py", line 66, in preprocess
    data = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\Josh\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 36188: character maps to <undefined>```
````

Comment: We can't do much with a hundred lines of code and no hint of where the error is. Python gave you a traceback. See if you can narrow the problem to a simple example focused on just that one thing. What's happening is that you are trying to convert a string to unicode using "charmap" (windows code page 1252) but it encountered the invalid characters. This may be a utf-16 file. Find out where that happens and take a look at the file or string.

Comment: I have updated to post to include the traceback

Comment: You have to specify encoding when you open the file: like file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")

Comment: How should I do this in my code, as I am not seeing anything that looks like that line of code will fit in?

Comment: @joshieman06, You need to do it in the lines, `open(os.path.join(args.init_from, 'config.pkl'), 'rb')`, `open(os.path.join(args.init_from, 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb')` and in every place where you are trying to Open and Read a File. Thanks!

Comment: How do I find the encoding? I have tried utf8 and utf16 but I still get the exact same error

Comment: On a windows machine converting to Ansi does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there was a weird character in the text file. All I had to do was replace all the weird symbols with the correct symbol. Thanks for all he help!

Comment: Next post take time to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

GIGO: Garbage-in-Garbage-out.
Please check the input (file) for special characters.

I got this error on "contents = file.read()"
because of the "heart" in the input text.

Here is the input text:
"I am an iOS and Web Developer. I ❤️ coffee and motorcycles."